# mod_rewrite is not available

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My client has old GoDaddy window hosting with mod_rewrite not available. I build an app using CodeIgniter that work fine on my server. But when I uploaded application to his hosting account it started giving 404 error.

Long story short I need it to work without mod_rewrite. I enable

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

In configuration file

but `index.php` is not being added to links. When I add

```
index.php to $config['base_url']
```

the CSS and JavaScript don’t get loaded.

Comment: are you using `base_url()` ?

Comment: yes. $config['base_url'] = http://host/site. If i add index.php to base url the css and javascript dont work but links don't give 404

Comment: you shouldn't add for css and js file the `index.php`

Comment: I know i just add it to base_url. CodeIgnitor add it to every link that has base_url

Comment: Tell your client to use a different plan or a more reasonable host. Windows hosting without any kind of URL-rewriting engine is not reasonable.

Comment: @Waqas IIS has rewrite mode as well. Have you tried to get it working ?

Comment: Well its a shared hosting. Can't really change a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `site_url()` for links and `base_url()` for js and css files.

```
echo base_url(); // http://example.com/website
echo site_url(); // http://example.com/website/index.php
```

If you want a URL access to a resource (such as css, js, image), use `base_url()`, otherwise, `site_url()` is better.